# onClickListener is called earlier than Fragment onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-button

I have an Recycler.Adapter and my `onBindViewHolder` is like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String url = urls.get(position);
        final width_height wh = whs.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setClickable(true);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url).resize(wh.width, wh.height).centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView);
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "");
                dialogFragment.setImage(url);
                dialogFragment.setRating(0);
            }
        });
        holder.textView.setText(position + "");
        holder.textView.setClickable(true);
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "");
                dialogFragment.setImage(url);
                dialogFragment.setRating(0);
            }
        });
}
```

The dialogFragment is already instantiated in the contructor of Adapter. However, its onCreateView has not been called yet when the holder is clicked. And the `setImage` and `setRating` need to modify its imageView and RatingBar, which are null unless the onCreateView of the fragment is called. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `DialogFragment.show` commits asynchronously. In your case you'd want it to use `DialogFragment.showNow` instead so it commits synchronously.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    dialogFragment.showNow(fragmentManager, "");
    dialogFragment.setImage(url);
    dialogFragment.setRating(0);
}
```

Otherwise I'd suggest to create new `DialogFragment` every time the button is clicked, and pass image url and rating as arguments before it is shown.

Answer (score 0):

A more correct way would be to have the `setImage` method and `setRating` method check for null. If null, they should save the value to variable, and onCreate should use those values to set.
For example (not tested);

```
void setImage(src) {
    if (mImage == null)
        mImageSource = src;
    else
        mImage.setImage(src);
 }

void onCreateView(...) {
    ...
    if (mImageSource != null)
       mImage.setImage(mImageSource);
    mImageSource = null;
}
```

This way you can correctly use the asynchronous dialog calls.